# How to remove all Text before and after in notepad++

Tags: gps, notepad++, drone.io, gpx, srt

I have GPS .SRT file of DJI Mavic Pro, I want to only Longitude and Latitude values, and delete all other text.
GPS string as per below

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,020
[iso : 450] [shutter : 1/50.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : 0.3] [ct : 5500] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.144090] [longtitude : 76.072992] [altitude: 285.026001] </font>

2
00:00:00,020 --> 00:00:00,040
[iso : 450] [shutter : 1/50.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : 0.3] [ct : 5500] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.144090] [longtitude : 76.072992] [altitude: 285.026001] </font>

3
00:00:00,040 --> 00:00:00,059
[iso : 450] [shutter : 1/50.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : 0.3] [ct : 5500] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.144090] [longtitude : 76.072992] [altitude: 285.026001] </font>
```

I want only from above string

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,020
[longtitude : 76.072992] [altitude: 285.026001]

2
00:00:00,020 --> 00:00:00,040
[longtitude : 76.072992] [altitude: 285.026001]

3
00:00:00,040 --> 00:00:00,059
[longtitude : 76.072992] [altitude: 285.026001]
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the following find and replace in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^.*(\[longtitude : \d+(?:\.\d+)?\] \[altitude: \d+(?:\.\d+)?\]) <\/font>$
Replace: $1
```

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IZzJL1/2) showing that the replacement logic is working.  Please run this regex in multiline mode from Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

You may also like  ...

Find:`^.*?(\[long.*\]).*`
Replace all:`$1`